# can I split a numeric string using multiple separators in a Swift closure?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, closures

I have a string array with fractional numbers and decimal numbers.

```
    let stringArray = [ "0.0", "193.16", "5/4", "503.42", "696.58", "25/16", "1082.89", "2/1"]
```

Each array element is mapped in a closure where numbers are extracted from the string.

```
    let values = stringArray.map { s -> Double in
```

*either fractional (see [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41312098/2348597))*

```
    let splitStrings = s.characters.split(separator: "/").map(String.init).map({ Double($0) })
```

*or decimal*

```
    let splitStrings = s.characters.split(separator: ".").map(String.init).map({ Double($0) })
```

**Question**: In Swift is there a way to split the string using more than one separator so a single closure can return fractional values or decimal values ?

*(continuation of closure)*

```
switch (token)) {
case "/"  :
        print( "fraction")

        let pathA = splitString[0]!/splitString[1]!
        return pathA

case "."  :
        print( "decimal")

        let upperSplit = splitString[0]!
        let lowerSplit = splitString[1]! * 0.1  // restore decimal point
        let pathB = upperSplit+lowerSplit
        return pathB
        }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to split a string like `"193.16"` at the decimal point? You can convert it to a `Double` directly.

Comment: Why is the your variable of array of strings named `string`? That's really confusing.

Comment: @Martin R, correct, splitting is only necessary for fractional numbers. If the closure can identify either fractional or decimal number, perform division for the fractional and convert `"193.16"` directly to `Double,` I'll be more than satisfied.

Comment: @rmaddy, point taken. I renamed it. Hopefully stringArray is clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to create floating point numbers from
either a decimal representation or a fraction, then there is no
need to split the string at the decimal point.

You can try to convert the string with `Double(string)`,
and if that fails, split it at the slash and convert numerator
and denominator separately:

```
func doubleFromDecimalOrFraction(s: String) -> Double? {
    // Try to convert from decimal representation:
    if let value = Double(s) {
        return value
    }
    // Try to convert from fractional format:
    if let range = s.range(of: "/"),
        let num = Double(s.substring(to: range.lowerBound)),
        let den = Double(s.substring(from: range.upperBound)) {
        return num/den
    }
    // Invalid format
    return nil
}
```

(Instead of returning `nil` for invalid input you might also
consider to `throw` an error, to abort the execution with
`fatalError()`, or to return some default value.)

This "utility function" can then be applied each array element:

```
let strings = [ "0.0", "193.16", "5/4", "503.42", "696.58", "25/16", "1082.89", "2/1"]
let values = strings.flatMap(doubleFromDecimalOrFraction)
```

Comment: this completely unpacks the question simplifying the problem. This has to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

### Split by more than one separator

#### Using `split`

Swift 4

```
let s = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let splitted = s.characters.split { [",", "[", "]"].contains($0.description) }
```

Swift 3

```
let s = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let splitted = s.characters.split { [",", "[", "]"].contains($0.description) }
```

Swift 2

```
let s = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let splitted = s.characters.split(isSeparator: {[",", "[", "]"].contains($0)}) }
```

---

#### Using characterSet

Swift 4

```
let str = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let separatorSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",[]")
let comps = str.components(separatedBy: separatorSet)
```

Swift 3

```
let str = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let separatorSet = CharacterSet(charactersInString: ",[]")
let comps = str.components(separatedBy: separatorSet)
```

Swift 2

```
let str = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let separatorSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",[]")
let comps = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separatorSet)
```

---

No matter what method we will use, and as a result, you will receive array. Without the information, which separator was used

If you need only convert String to Double then

```
let array = stringArray.compactMap { element -> Double? in
    if let value = Double(element) {
        return value
    }
    let parts = element.components(separatedBy: "/")
    guard parts.count == 2, 
          let dividend = Double(parts[0]), 
          let divisor = Double(parts[1]), 
          divisor != 0
    else {
        return nil
    }
    return dividend / divisor
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `return dividend/divisor`.?

Comment: Right. my mistake. Thank you @vacawama

Comment: @ Adrian,  `return dividends/divisor` works correctly (I'm still checking the rest)

Answer (score 0):

Define extension (Swift 4):

```
extension String {
    func split(separators: String) -> [String] {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: separators))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let str = "aaa-bbb_ccc/ddd"
let arr = str.split(separators: "-_/")
```

Result :

`["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]`