# How to use Optionals to stop a compiler error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I want a way to detect input errors in a string and notify the user.
Take the following example:

```
    let fraction            = "15/8"

    let fractionArray       = fraction.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let numerator           = Double(fractionArray[0])
    let denominator         = Double(fractionArray[1])
    var linearFactor        = numerator! / denominator!

    print(numerator!, "/", denominator!, " = ", linearFactor)
```

But if I force unwrap, invalid characters in the string will force a compile error and I’d rather notify the user that the input string contains an invalid fraction. Optional chaining seems like the way to go but I can’t get the syntax right.

In my code (*below*), I place the optional chaining operator next to the array as shown including `fraction?.components(separatedBy: “/“)` but Fix-it tells me to delete it.

If there is a better way than optional chaining to address this problem can someone please explain what I might have missed when I searched for answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/2348597) so I can make the code work ? Thanks

```
    let fraction            = “15/8”

    if let fractionArray    = fraction?.components(separatedBy: “/“) {
    let numerator           = Double(fractionArray[0])
    let denominator         = Double(fractionArray[1])
    var linearFactor        = numerator / denominator

    print(numerator, "/", denominator, " = ", linearFactor)
        } else {
            print(“Invalid. Re-enter fraction”)
        }
```

Comment: `fraction?.components(separatedBy: “/“) seems like the most obvious place` — What? It's opposite of obvious. `fraction` is definitely not an Optional, but result of `components(separatedBy:)` is. And `?` — is not declaration here, but Optional chaining operator.

Comment: Actually both answers to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336818/can-i-split-a-numeric-string-using-multiple-separators-in-a-swift-closure show how to use *optional binding* instead of the forced unwrap.

Comment: See also [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil) for a list of good examples how to avoid forced unwrapping. – Btw, unwrapping nil is a *runtime error,* not a compile error.

Comment: @Martin R, the latest post is a simplified digest of something more elaborate that evolved since my earlier post. I'll certainly edit my question once I finish comparing it with the two previous answers.

Comment: In the elaborate version I compared optional values to nil so I'll look at that post too.

Comment: @user28434, point taken. I've edited accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. fraction is **String** not **String?** so you don't have to use fraction?
2. components return **[]** not **[]?**, so you can use fractionArray without unwrap anything
3. the only thing you have to unwrap is **numerator** and **denominator**, their type is **Double?**
4. Thanks @OOPer, should check denominator != 0
5. Thanks @Martin R, should check fractionArray.count == 2

so I'll refactor to the following code:

```
let fraction = "15/8"
let fractionArray = fraction.components(separatedBy: "/")
guard let numerator = Double(fractionArray[0]), 
    let denominator = Double(fractionArray[1]),
    denominator != 0,
    fractionArray.count == 2 else {
    print("Invalid. Re-enter fraction, or denominator == 0, or fractionArray.count != 2")
    return
}
let linearFactor = numerator / denominator
print(numerator, "/", denominator, " = ", linearFactor)
```

Comment: This may not be the main topic, but if you want to make your code crash-safe, you'd better check `denominator` is not zero.

Comment: thx, you are right, but 1.0/0.0 = inf, 0.0/0.0 = nan will be the results in the above codes

Comment: Right. My mistake, `inf` and `nan` may be something to avoid, but division by zero with `Double`s does not crash. Sorry.

Comment: thx @OOPer ! update the solution

Comment: You may also want to check that the array has two elements (as it is done in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41337068/1187415 to the author's previous question).

Comment: The array count should be checked *before* accessing the array elements.

Comment: @SaiCYLi, thanks, your first three points helped me understand something I missed in the answer to the previous Stackoverflow question. I got your code running once I created a new project (it didn't run in Playground). This is the accepted answer.