# optional chaining in Swift 3: why does one example work and not the other?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Here is a detailed account of a problem following my [previous post on Swift optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41358964/2348597).

Thanks to leads given [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337042/2348597) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337068/2348597) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41359262/2348597), I am able to read fractions (*for harmonic ratios*) or decimals (*for cents*) from a string array to calculate the frequencies of notes in musical scales.

Each element in the string array is first tested to see if it contains a `/` or a `.` One of two functions then identifies input errors using optional chaining so both fractional and decimal numbers conform to rules outlined in this [tuning file format](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/scl_format.html).

Example 1 and 1a shows what happens with correctly entered data in both formats.

1. Scale *with a mixture of fractions and decimals*

   ```
                   C      D            E      F            G            Ab       B             C’      
   let tuning = [ "1/1", "193.15686", "5/4", "503.42157", "696.57843", "25/16", "1082.89214", "2/1"]
   ```

*the column in the debug area shows input data (top down), row shows output frequencies (l-to-r).*

```
    Optional("1/1")
    Optional("193.15686")
    Optional("5/4")
    Optional("503.42157")
    Optional("696.57843")
    Optional("25/16")
    Optional("1082.89214")
    Optional("2/1")
    [261.62599999999998, 292.50676085897425, 327.03249999999997, 349.91970174951047, 391.22212058238728, 408.79062499999998, 489.02764963627084, 523.25199999999995]
```

Examples 2 & 3 show how both functions react to *bad* input (i.e. wrongly entered data).

2. bad fractions are reported *(e.g. missing denominator prints a message)*

   ```
   Optional("1/1")
   Optional("5/")
   User input error - invalid fraction: frequency now being set to 0.0 Hertz 
   Optional("500.0")
   Optional("700.0")
   Optional("2/1")
   [261.62599999999998, 0.0, 349.22881168708938, 391.99608729493866, 523.25199999999995]
   ```
3. bad decimals are not reported *(e.g. after 700 there is no .0 - this should produce a message)*

   ```
   Optional("1/1")
   Optional("5/4")
   Optional("500.0")
   Optional("700")
   Optional("2/1")
   [261.62599999999998, 327.03249999999997, 349.22881168708938, 0.0, 523.25199999999995]
   ```

NOTE: In addition to the report 0.0 (Hz) appears in the row when an optional is nil. This was inserted elsewhere in the code (*where it is explained in context with a comment*.)

The problem in a nutshell ? the function for fractions reports a fault whereas the function for decimal numbers fails to detect bad input.

Both functions use optional chaining with a guard statement. This works for faulty fractions but nothing I do will make the function report a faulty input condition for decimals. After checking the code thoroughly I’m convinced the problem lies in the conditions I’ve set for the guard statement. But I just can’t get this right. Can anyone please explain what I did wrong ?

**Tuner.swift**

```
import UIKit

class Tuner {

    var tuning                      = [String]()
    let tonic: Double               = 261.626   // frequency of middle C
    var index                       = -1
    let centsPerOctave: Double      = 1200.0    // mandated by Scala tuning file format
    let formalOctave: Double        = 2.0       // Double for stretched-octave tunings

init(tuning: [String]) {
    self.tuning                     = tuning

    let frequency                   = tuning.flatMap(doubleFromDecimalOrFraction)
    print(frequency)

}


func doubleFromDecimalOrFraction(s: String?) -> Double {

    index                           += 1
    let whichNumericStringType      = s
    print(whichNumericStringType as Any)        // eavesdrop on String?

    var possibleFrequency: Double?

    //  first process decimal.
    if (whichNumericStringType?.contains("."))!             {
        possibleFrequency           = processDecimal(s: s)
    }

    //  then process fractional.
    if (whichNumericStringType?.contains("/"))!             {
        possibleFrequency           = processFractional(s: s)
    }

    // Insert "0.0" marker. Remove when processDecimal works
    let noteFrequency               = possibleFrequency
    let zeroFrequency               = 0.0
    // when noteFrequency? is nil, possibleFrequency is set to zeroFrequency
    let frequency                   = noteFrequency ?? zeroFrequency

    return frequency    // TO DO let note: (index: Int, frequency: Double)

    }


func processFractional(s: String?) -> Double?   {

    var fractionArray               = s?.components(separatedBy: "/")

    guard let numerator             = Double((fractionArray?[0])!.digits),
        let denominator             = Double((fractionArray?[1])!.digits),
        numerator                   > 0,
        denominator                 != 0,
        fractionArray?.count        == 2
        else
    {
        let possibleFrequency       = 0.0
        print("User input error - invalid fraction: frequency now being set to \(possibleFrequency) Hertz ")
        return possibleFrequency
        }
    let possibleFrequency           = tonic * (numerator / denominator)
    return possibleFrequency
        }


func processDecimal(s: String?) -> Double?      {

    let decimalArray                = s?.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard let _                     = s,
        decimalArray?.count         == 2
        else
    {
        let denominator             = 1
        let possibleFrequency       = 0.0
        print("User input error (value read as \(s!.digits)/\(denominator) - see SCL format, http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/scl_format.html): frequency now being forced to \(possibleFrequency) Hertz ")
        return possibleFrequency
        }
    let power                       = Double(s!)!/centsPerOctave
    let possibleFrequency           = tonic * (formalOctave**power)
    return possibleFrequency
        }
    }


extension String {

    var digits: String {
    return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
        }
    }


precedencegroup Exponentiative {

    associativity: left
    higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence

    }


infix operator ** : Exponentiative

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{
    return pow(num, power)
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // test pitches: rational fractions and decimal numbers (currently 'good')
    let tuning = ["1/1", "5/4", "500.0", "700.0", "2/1"]

    // Diatonic scale: rational fractions
    //       let tuning = [ "1/1", "9/8", "5/4", "4/3", "3/2", "27/16", "15/8", "2/1"]

    // Mohajira: rational fractions
    //    let tuning = [ "21/20", "9/8", "6/5", "49/40", "4/3", "7/5", "3/2", "8/5", "49/30", "9/5", "11/6", "2/1"]

    // Diatonic scale: 12-tET
    //    let tuning = [ "0.0", "200.0", "400.0", "500", "700.0", "900.0", "1100.0", "1200.0"]

    // Diatonic scale: mixed 12-tET and rational fractions
    //    let tuning = [ "0.0", "9/8", "400.0", "4/3", "700.0", "27/16", "1100.0", "2/1"]

    // Diatonic scale: 19-tET
    //     let tuning = [ "0.0", "189.48", "315.8", "505.28", "694.76", "884.24", "1073.72", "1200.0"]

    // Diatonic 1/4-comma meantone scale. Pietro Aaron's temperament (1523) : mixed cents and rational fractions
    //    let tuning = [ "1/1", "193.15686", "5/4", "503.42157", "696.57843", "25/16", "1082.89214", "2/1"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _ = Tuner(tuning: tuning)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your processDecimal func for when your string = "700"? I would interested in know what the decimalArray.count is.

Comment: There's a lot of explicit forced unwrapping above (`!`), e.g. in `processFractional`: this should generally be avoided as it can lead to runtime crashes. E.g. for the `guard` in `processFractional(...)`, `Double((fractionArray?[0])!.digits)`, you could make this safe with optional chaining and the `nil` coalescing operator, e.g. `Double((fractionArray?[0])?.digits ?? "failMe")`.

Comment: All three answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/41337042/2348597,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41337068/2348597, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41359262/2348597 to your previous questions solve the task without any forced unwrapping.

Comment: @Martin R, can you clarify one thing please - `let numerator = Double((parts?[0])!.digits),` - forced unwrapping ? or a guard condition to catch nil ? I understood this to be the latter.

Comment: `optionalExpr!` is a forced unwrapping and causes the program to crash if `optionalExpr` is `nil`. `fractionArray?[0]` in your code is *optional chaining*. But why did you make the parameter of `func doubleFromDecimalOrFraction(s: String?)` an optional at all? That seems unnecessary to me. – I don't want to sound rude, but you already got 3 good answers solving exactly your task. Please try to understand them. Ask for clarification if necessary.

Comment: @Martin R, I appreciate your comments (I don't find them rude). I'll work more with these answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem in a nutshell ? the function for fractions reports a fault whereas the function for decimal numbers fails to detect bad input.

The function for decimal numbers does detect “bad” input. However, `"700"` does not contain `"."`, and you only call `processDecimal(s:)` if the string does contain `"."`. If the string doesn't contain `"."` and also doesn't contain `"/"`, `doubleFromDecimalOrFraction(s:)` doesn't call any function to parse the string.

Comment: Good spot, missed that.

Comment: @Martin R, @robmayoff, this has to be the reason I had such trouble with decimal and not fraction. I know how to introduce a third function to process strings without `“.”` or `“/“` Or will it be better with a reworked version of both functions “without any forced unwrapping” (which I need to get on top of) ?

Comment: @rob mayor, accepted. You pin-pointed it! I'll edit the post with my solution first thing next year!